# Is it possible to start a colorbox based on a specified index?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I would like to be able to pass in the index of the image I want colorbox to start on when it opens.  So if the user clicks on image 8 of 12 I still want the group to start in the lightbox on image 3.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post some code? Also, if user clicks 8/12, why not show image 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it is to fire up colorbox on a list of images then call

```
$('selector').eq(indexhere).click();
```

Thank's for taking a look hookedonwinter.